# Design a circuit for a function

Tags: optimization, boolean-algebra

I am so confused on this problem. We are given a function $f$ and told to design a circuit that has four inputs labeled $b_3,...,b_0$, and an output $f$, where $f = 1$ if the 4-bit input pattern is a valid BCD digit; otherwise $f = 0$. We want to use minimum cost implementation.

Here is the function: $f = b_3b_0 + \bar b_2 b_1b_0 + b_2b_1 \bar b_0$

I am confused on how to design this with minimum cost. So my circuit will obviously need to be able to perform AND, OR, and NOT.

Here is what I am coming up with, but I don't think it is right by any means: https://gyazo.com/cb9fffc430c03c25c55dd962e943cea1

My circuit makes use of seemingly way too many components for this to be correct. Can anyone help?

Comment: How are you defining cost?

Comment: By the least amount of components that can be used. I.e., 5 components is less than 15 components.

Comment: What do you define as components?

Comment: Everything besides the input values (b3,...b0) are components. So all of the shapes (which are the symbols for AND, NOT, and OR) are all components, and all the lines to each are components as they represent physical wires.

Comment: What about Nand?  Nor?  Xor?  Xnor? Are you really counting all wires as components?  What about splitters?

Comment: I didn't use NAND or NOR because I didn't think this one used them. If there is someway that they can be used to minimize cost that'd be great. I can ask my professor about the wires counting as components. I may have misheard on that. We haven't talked about splitters yet so I don't know what they are.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34562/discussion-between-generic-user007-and-danielv).